# apache server 2.4: is there a way to hook into thread init event?

Tags: c, multithreading, apache, curl

I'm developing an apache module on version 2.4 and using the power of MPM workers/events.

I want each thread to have it's own `libcurl` handle (the module is creating an http request using curl) so that no curl handle will be shared on more than one thread (as mentioned in `libcurl` [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html) this is bad).

I'm trying to hook into the thread initialisation process to define a handle on each thread, something like:

```
apr_status init_worker_thread(apr_pool_t *p, void *thread_local) {
   thread_local->curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
   ...
```

}

I could not find any documentation on this kind of hook, is that possible? If not, is there a work around? how can I reuse my curl handle for better performance (mainly connection persistence) through multi threading (calling `curl_easy_cleanup` on each request is not a good idea).

BTW: I'm aware of making this module only relevant for MPM module supported versions.

Comment: "using **the power** of MPM workers/events." - are they magic?

Comment: `thread_local->curl_handle` is not possible.

Comment: @Olaf Yes I know it's not possible I was looking for the method that make this possible to add local data to a thread using some kind of hook (like child_init hook)